# Как сделать прозрачными Edit, Memo, RichText?

Tags: delphi

Весь интернет облазил, никак не могу сделать Edit, Memo, RichText прозрачными.
WinAPI использовал, но как-то безуспешно или я что-то неправильно делал. В общем прошу помощи, может кто подскажет или скажет ссылки на подобного рода компоненты, буду признателен.

Answer (score 2):

Если, допустим, есть форма и на ней есть Edit:

1. Если у Edit установить свойство ParentColor = true, то он будет такого же цвета, как форма.
2. Если у формы свойство TransparentColor = true, то на ней цвет TransparentColorValue 
   будет прозрачным. Следовательно, если form.TransparentColorValue = form.Color и 
   edit.ParentColor = form.TransparentColor = true, то всё это будет прозрачным.
3. Если же необходимо, чтобы только само окно Edit было прозрачным, то можно
   добавить на форму компонент Image, заполненный каким-нибудь рисунком.

У меня вот так :)

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('D:\1.bmp');  
end;
```

Также можно не загружать рисунок, а "залить" Image. У меня вот так :)

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
with Image1.Canvas do begin  
  Brush.Color := clMedGray;  
  FillRect(Rect(0,0,ClipRect.Right,ClipRect.Bottom));  
end;  
end;
```

Наверняка ещё есть куча вариантов, но надеюсь, это хоть как-то помогло )

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Но тут вот такая ситуация. У меня есть бэкграунд и на нём надо разместить например Edit. Но когда размещаешь его на фоне бэкграунда (картинки), остаётся белая дырка.Вот мне надо её закрыть, сделать так, чтобы был виден только текст без белой дырки).

Comment: То есть, чтобы в поле Edit был виден только текст? А на фоне чего?

Comment: Да,именно так)На фоне любой картинки)

Comment: Ну, для заливки, меняем Edit.Color, а на фоне картинки пока не знаю.  
Может как-то сделать ещё одну форму позади первой с нужной картинкой?

Comment: В том и проблема, что надо всё на одной форме сделать.

Comment: Придётся наверно свой контрол писать.